# Python reads numerals as "NoneType" from JSON file (Python Crash Course 16-8. Recent Earthquakes)

Tags: python, json

I am trying to make a map of earthquakes. Here is JSON file https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.geojson
When i am reading magnitudes from file it reads numerals as "NoneType".  Why?

```
import json
from plotly.graph_objs import Scattergeo, Layout
from plotly import offline

# Explore the structure of the data.
filename = 'data/all_earthquakes.json'
with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    all_eq_data = json.load(f)

all_eq_dicts = all_eq_data['features']

mags, lons, lats, hover_texts = [], [], [], []
eq_title = all_eq_data['metadata']['title']
for eq_dict in all_eq_dicts:
    mags.append(eq_dict['properties']['mag'])
    lons.append(eq_dict['geometry']['coordinates'][0])
    lats.append(eq_dict['geometry']['coordinates'][1])
    hover_texts.append(eq_dict['properties']['title'])


# Map the earthquakes.
data = [{
    'type': 'scattergeo',
    'lon': lons,
    'lat': lats,
    'text': hover_texts,
    'marker': {
        'size': [5*mag for mag in mags],
        'color': mags,
        'colorscale': 'Viridis',
        'reversescale': True,
        'colorbar': {'title': 'Magnitude'},
    },
}]
my_layout = Layout(title=eq_title)

fig = {'data': data, 'layout': my_layout}
offline.plot(fig, filename='global_earthquakes.html')
```

unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to that page and search for `mag":null`, you'll see that there's at least two spots where the `"mag"` is `null`.

If you want a simple fix

```
[5*mag for mag in mags if mag is not None]
```

will work if you want to simply remove them, or

```
[None if mag is None else 5*mag for mag in mags]
```

if you want to translate them to `None` (or some other default value).